# List all MAC Addresses of Router

Tags: router, ip, mac-address

I have a modem which has an embedded router inside, I was led to believe by sources on the internet that each network terminal has its own MAC address. By typing the default gateway IP I managed to find only one MAC address. Can anyone share any information and shed some light on this problem?

I also used the arp -a command to list the MAC addresses in my cache and found many static addresses having an IP starting with 224. Not sure what this represents, I also would like to add that I am very new to the networking field.

[image: arp -a command]

Additional Questions:

1. Does WiFi also have its own MAC address?
2. Does WiFi have its own broadcast domain?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the router model? Each vendor has its own commands for doing this.

Comment: Thank you for your help Fahad Yousuf your answer is great and everything I was looking for.

Comment: @Bonavia, you should accept the answer if it answered your question.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all to clarify, every device which is connected to a Layer-2 network using an interface such as an Ethernet Interface, WiFi Adapter (802.11a/b/g/n/ac) has its own MAC address. On top of this it can have multiple Layer-3 addresses (IP Addresses) for its MAC addresses. For ordinary PCs and wireless devices it is normally 1 IP assigned to 1 MAC address for their connected adapters (Ethernet or WiFi).

First off 224.x.x.x is used for MultiCast addresses. To learn more about these [here](http://www.firewall.cx/networking-topics/general-networking/108-multicast-ip-list.html) is a starting point. The packets destined to these IPs will actually reach multiple recipients who are members of the multicast group represented by the IP.

Now back to the list of MAC addresses. Your PC learns the MAC addresses of other systems in its broadcast domain when it tries to communicate with them using their IP addresses. This learning process is done using the "Address Resolution Protocol". [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jncvd6JDoc) is a nice video showing how ARP works. The dynamic entries in your shown output are learned via "ARP".

As for getting to know the MAC addresses of everything in your broadcast domain. Your ARP table will only show cached entries of MAC address to IP Address mappings which your device has recently learned usin ARP. The ARP Cache is constantly updated as you try to reach more and more IPs in your broadcast domain. You can try pinging different IPs in your subnet (broadcast domain) and after each new address you ping, check your 'arp -a' output. You will see new MAC addresses pop up for addresses which actually exist and are alive in your network and 'incomplete' entries for IPs which did not reply to your ARP queries.

Hope this has helped.